# dll does not contain valid metadata: compile in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have a dll file and a script in c#, the two in the same directory.
when I try to compile the script I get this message:

> error CS0009: Metadata file `/home/Lab/Bureau/Csharp/zkemkeeper.dll' does not contain valid metadata
>
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 1 warnings

Comment: So is the DLL actually a managed DLL? Please give us more context.

Comment: I just came across the same problem with Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.3 using Mono JIT compiler version 5.20.1.34 for a WebAPI project targetting net471. Downgrading to Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0 starts kicking out netstandard 2.0 errors about System.Object. I am using Fedora 31 btw.